# Why is my jQuery selector `... input :gt(0)` not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to jQuery.
*To be short,*

when I have a DOM structure like this:

```
<table id="hello" border="1"> <tr>
<td><input id="examsdatesheet-0-1st-exam_date" placeholder="0"></td>
<td><input id="examsdatesheet-1-1st-exam_date" placeholder="1"></td>
<td><input id="examsdatesheet-2-1st-exam_date" placeholder="2"></td>
</tr> </table>
```

The following line gives me an array of all inputs having an index greater than 0

```
 var allnext = $('#hello td input:gt(0)');
```

I changed my DOM structure to this:

```
<div class="exams-date-sheet-form">
<table><td>
<div class="form-group field-examsdatesheet-0-1st-exam_date required">
<input type="text" id="examsdatesheet-0-1st-exam_date" class="form-control hasDatepicker" name="ExamsDatesheet[0][1st][exam_date]" value="21/06/2016">
</div>
</td>
<td>
<div class="form-group field-examsdatesheet-1-1st-exam_date required">
<input type="text" id="examsdatesheet-1-1st-exam_date" class="form-control hasDatepicker" name="ExamsDatesheet[0][1st][exam_date]" value="21/06/2016">
</div>
</td></table></div>
```

Now when I try to select all elements having index greater than 0, this should work:

```
var allnext = $('.exams-date-sheet-form table tbody tr td input :gt(0)');
```

BUT IT DOES NOT!
 How can I store the above required elements in an array?

Comment: you don't have tbody and tr tags in your html and also the space beetween input and :gt(0) is not needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `.exams-date-sheet-form input:gt(0)` as your selector (note the omitted space), or rely on the `slice` method of the jQuery object.

The `:gt` selector needs to be linked to your `input` selector; separating them with a space makes the selector interpreted as a descendant wildcard like `.exams-date-sheet-form input *:gt(0)`, and since `input` elements have no children, nothing is ever matched.

```js
// Using `:gt(0)`
var allnext = $('.exams-date-sheet-form input:gt(0)')
// Using `.slice(1)`
var allnext = $('.exams-date-sheet-form input').slice(1)

console.log(allnext.length) //=> 1
console.log(allnext[0])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="exams-date-sheet-form">
<table><td>
<div class="form-group field-examsdatesheet-0-1st-exam_date required">
<input type="text" id="examsdatesheet-0-1st-exam_date" class="form-control hasDatepicker" name="ExamsDatesheet[0][1st][exam_date]" value="21/06/2016">
</div>
</td>
<td>
<div class="form-group field-examsdatesheet-1-1st-exam_date required">
<input type="text" id="examsdatesheet-1-1st-exam_date" class="form-control hasDatepicker" name="ExamsDatesheet[0][1st][exam_date]" value="21/06/2016">
</div>
</td></table></div>
```

Comment: can you kindly specify what was wrong in my selector? was it the omitted space?

Comment: I updated my answer with an explanation. Hope that helps!

Comment: I don't know who is the downvoter, but your answer seems to be perfect. It  worked!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you select all elements with jquery selector and filter them using javascript filter? Like this:

```
var allnext = $('exams-date-sheet-form table tbody tr td input')
    .filter(function(item, index){
        return index > 0;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

By using 3 plain JavaScript methods you can accomplish your objective:

> ```
>  var inputArray = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input'));
> ```

- [`document.querySelectorAll();`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll): Collect `<inputs>` to NodeList
- [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from): Change NodeList into an array
- [`Array.shift()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array): Remove the first `<input>` from array

BTW, added `<tr>` to `<table>`. I believe it's required of every `<table>` to have at least one `<tr>`.

**SNIPPET**

```js
const inputArray = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input'));

inputArray.shift();

console.log(inputArray);
```

```html
<div class="exams-date-sheet-form">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="form-group field-examsdatesheet-0-1st-exam_date required">
          <input type="text" id="examsdatesheet-0-1st-exam_date" class="form-control hasDatepicker" name="ExamsDatesheet[0][1st][exam_date]" value="21/06/2016">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="form-group field-examsdatesheet-2-2nd-exam_date required">
          <input type="text" id="examsdatesheet-2-2nd-exam_date" class="form-control hasDatepicker" name="ExamsDatesheet[0][2nd][exam_date]" value="22/06/2016">
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```